# Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. SELECT Command Failed

Tags: teradata

I am using the below query and it gives error that "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. SELECT Command Failed."

`SELECT TOP 100 X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ, CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT) AS COUNT_ROW   FROM S_CONTACT WHERE X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%';`

I changed the above query as written below but the error still persists.

`SELECT TOP 100 X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ, CAST(COUNT(X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ) AS BIGINT) AS COUNT_ROW   FROM S_CONTACT WHERE X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%';`

Answer (score 1):

You presumably are missing a `GROUP BY` clause here:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT) AS COUNT_ROW
FROM S_CONTACT
WHERE
    X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'
GROUP BY
    X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ;
```

The exact error you were seeing with your original query has to do with that selecting `X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ` instructs Teradata to return a value for each *record* in the table, whereas `COUNT()` returns a value over the entire *table*.  It is not possible (in general) to mix aggregates and non aggregates in a select clause.

Comment: What is the reason for the 2nd query then, I haven't used any other attribute there. Morever I don't get what "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. SELECT Command Failed." means, can you explain it briefly, like when cani t occur.

Comment: SELECT TOP 100 X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ, CAST(COUNT(X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ) AS BIGINT) AS COUNT_ROW
FROM S_CONTACT WHERE X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'; Why the same error for this query?

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no `GROUP BY` clause.  You are selecting the count, which is a table level aggregate (i.e. it involves _all_ records).  You are also selecting `X_ISP_AFF_ADDR_SEQ`, which has a different value _for each record_.  _Which_ record's value do you want Teradata to select?  This is not clear, hence you get an error.